# Select data field json in array of text PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table `books` with field `json` in PostgreSQL 9.3.

```
CREATE TABLE books ( 
    id integer, 
    data json 
);
```

The rows of table

[image]

I need to execute `select` in field `author` (json) of the field `data` (table)

Example:

`select * from books where data->>'author' = 'Bob' or data->>'author' = 'Xavier'`

It is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-json.html ?

Comment: @pmac89 yes I saw, I tried this `SELECT * FROM books WHERE data#>>'author' = 'Bob';` but don't work. In field `name`(json) it works, see `SELECT * FROM books WHERE data->>'name' = 'Book the First';`  
I change `->>` to `#>>`

Comment: Why are you trying to change it from ->> to #>>?

Comment: I understood that `#>>` find array of text in json, bacause `->>` don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I understand your question now. The answer is very simple in regards to how you have things setup.

```
select * from books where data->>'author' = 'Bob' or data->>'author' = 'Xavier'
```

The reason ->> does not work is because the field 'author' is not of type string, it is actually of type array. So when you use #>> you need to specify the element of the array you need. Look here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

EDIT: Read through this, it will help you to understand how to access different parts of the JSON data field. 
http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/

Comment: I tried `select * from books where data#>>'{author,"Bob"}'` but don't works. Is correct the select command?

Comment: Not sure. My server only has PSQL version 9.2 and SQL Fiddle isn't working for me either. Maybe this will help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array

Comment: See that strange.
I have to records: `3 | {"a": 2, "b": ["c", "d"]}` and  `4 | {"a": 1, "b": {"c": "d", "e": true}}`. This `SELECT * FROM json_test WHERE data #>> '{b, c}' = 'd'` return recod `3`, but when execute `SELECT * FROM json_test WHERE data #>> '{b}' = 'd'` not result record 3.